# Redirect Traffic from NIC to Another NIC On Separate Networks While Using Remoting

Tags: windows, remoting, barcode-scanner, network-scan

The project I'm working on is to handle data capture from scan guns (Pocket PC 2003) and process this data on a host (Win XP) then into our inventory database on a separate server (Win 2000). This is all driven by the Remoting framework provided by MS and As Good As It Gets (http://gotcf.net). The application is complete enough for a general proof of concept with both the client and server working properly while in the emulator.

All is well until I began to test using actual scan guns. Due to security concerns, the scanners are on a separate network (for clarification the 10 network) than the server (the 15 network). My development machine has dual NIC connected to both networks and can communicate with both independently. However, I am having issues with my application receiving information from the 10 network using .Net Remoting, and then sending out information to the server on the 15 network via a third party app (Combination of ODBC, Btrieve, and OLE).

Is there anyway to process information from one network then update the server on another?

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

**Note:** I'm not very familiar with networking, thus I may be calling it the wrong name but the gun IP's start with 10.*.*.* and the server IP's start with 15.*.*.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to stem from both the NIC cards not set up properly and a so far unresolved issue with the frameworks I've chosen.

- To solve the NIC problem, the easiest solution I'd found had me clear the default gateway on the 10 network.
- <strike>The other issue deals with recreating the remoting objects after they've been destroyed. I currently have to warm boot the scanner in order to re-connect to the host. In order to correct this issue I'm going to contact As Good As It Gets to see what their input is.</strike>  *Damn firewall*

Answer (score 0):

So long as the computer's routing table is properly configured, you shouldn't have to worry about this from your application.  So long as you're using the proper IP addresses, the networking stack should take care of delivering things to the right place.

You might want to check the output of "route print" (at least I think that was available on WinXp -- if not, someone else will likely post the correct command for XP soon).  In any way, you should see what network destinations are configured for which interfaces.  You'll need to make sure that the server's IP on the 15 network will properly route via the interface you want (ie. the lowest-cost matching destination/netmask lists your 15 interface).